# How can I add auto_width to a Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, media-queries

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> entries = <String>[
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'I'
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: entries.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code I but the width equal to 150 so the app doesn't crash but I am trying to make the width of the Container 1/3 of the devise screen size so the screen will contain 3 container equally but when I trying with :

```
width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
```

an error occur :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
```

Is there any solution to my problem or is there any Widget I can use to do what I want ??

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get your intention...

but if you're trying to give a Container one third of the device width and you get an error using MediaQuery, try to build another widget that returns your Scaffold

e.g **MyApp** widget which returns a **MaterialApp** with the `home: MyHomePage()`

and a **MyHomePage** widget that returns the **Scaffold** and use MediaQuery within it.